# neo4j : Cannot perform data updates in a transaction that has performed schema updates

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Hi I am getting following error while saving NodeEntity object by using Neo4jTemplate

Cannot perform data updates in a transaction that has performed schema updates

Spring-data :-

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Neo4j Version : 2.X

Service :-

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addRepository(Repository repository) {
    template.save(repository);
}
```

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.InvalidTransactionTypeKernelException: Cannot perform data updates in a transaction that has performed schema updates.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation$TransactionType$2.upgradeToDataTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.upgradeToDataTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:212)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelStatement.dataWriteOperations(KernelStatement.java:84)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.createNode(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1033)
    ... 49 more

Answer (score 1):

SDN 3.0.0 needs now to have `base-package` configured in your Spring configuration.
Indeed, this is now needed since Neo4j 2.0.X doesn't allow insertion of index (schema change involved by your **first** `save` operation) in the same transaction as a data update (`save` of your entity in your case).

So if you use XML configuration for Spring, it would looks like:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="com.myApp.myDomainPackage" />
```

where `com.myApp.myDomainPackage` contains all the node entities.
instead of simple:

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
```

Comment: This is correct. The previous versions of SDN detected entities when they were first used with the library, e.g. on your `save()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Data updates and schema changes need to happen in separate transactions. If they would be allowed in the same transaction various sorts of weirdness would be possible.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I am doing update and schema change together? I am just saving the a object. How can I avoid this