# Spring data neo4j GraphProperty annotation - missing index

Tags: scala, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When reading the documentation for `GraphProperty` one can find that adding this annotation to field `Automatically indexes the property`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/GraphProperty.html

But it looks like it is not true (at least for `3.0.1`). If I understand this right, `SDN 3.0.1` uses label-based indexes by default. Here is my class:

```
object Neo4jAnnotations {
    type GraphId = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId @field
    type GraphProperty = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphProperty @field
    type Fetch = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch @field
    type RelatedTo = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo @field
    type Id = org.springframework.data.annotation.Id @field
    type Indexed = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Indexed @field
    type NodeEntity = org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity
}

import Neo4jAnnotations._
@NodeEntity
case class FlightDesignator(@Indexed @GraphProperty(propertyType = classOf[String]) carrier: Carrier,
                            @GraphProperty(propertyType = classOf[java.lang.Integer]) flightNumber: FlightNumber,
                            @GraphProperty(propertyType = classOf[String]) suffix: Option[Suffix] = None,
                            @GraphId id: java.lang.Long = null) {

  private def this() = this(null, null, null)
}
```

and my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(Array("persistence.common.repository", "persistence.set.repository", "persistence.list.repository"))
class Neo4jConfiguration extends org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration {

  private final val Path = "/db/graph.db"

  /*
  Packages that specify where to look for entity classes, if missing SDN does not create label based indexes.
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089640/neo4j-cannot-perform-data-updates-in-a-transaction-that-has-performed-schema-u
   */
  setBasePackage("domain.common", "domain.set", "domain.list")

  @Bean
  def graphDatabaseService(): GraphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(Path);

}
```

Now, when I load my context:

```
val a = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(classOf[Neo4jConfiguration])
```

in my logs I can see:

```
16:18:26.233 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.schema.SchemaIndexProvider - CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`)
16:18:26.233 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.query.CypherQueryEngine - Executing cypher query: CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`) params {}
16:18:27.005 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.schema.SchemaIndexProvider - CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`)
16:18:27.005 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.query.CypherQueryEngine - Executing cypher query: CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`) params {}
16:18:27.315 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.schema.SchemaIndexProvider - CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`)
16:18:27.316 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.query.CypherQueryEngine - Executing cypher query: CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`) params {}
16:18:27.339 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.schema.SchemaIndexProvider - CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`)
16:18:27.339 [main] DEBUG o.s.d.n.s.query.CypherQueryEngine - Executing cypher query: CREATE INDEX ON :`FlightDesignator`(`carrier`) params {}
```

and when I execute `schema` command using `neo4j-shell` I can see:

```
Indexes
  ON :FlightDesignator(carrier) ONLINE
```

but there are no indexes for other properties that are annotated with `GraphProperty` and w/o `Indexed`. Is it a bug or just someone forgot to update javadoc?

Comment: You're mistaken. The @Indexed annotation makes properties indexed.

Comment: Ok, so why it says in the documentation of `GraphProperty`: `Automatically indexes the property`? 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/GraphProperty.html